# mciSendString/winmm.dll - Playing an Audio file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, audio

I am working on a program in Visual Basic 2008, I am required to have different types of sounds with varying volumes. Hence My.Computer.Audio.Play is not a valid option.

I decided to use mciSendString instead and found the following code

```
Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" _
(ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, _
ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer

    mciSendString("close myWAV", Nothing, 0, 0)
    Dim fileName1 As String = 
    mciSendString("open " & fileName1 & " type mpegvideo alias myWAV", Nothing, 0, 0)
    mciSendString("play myWAV", Nothing, 0, 0)

    'min Volume is 1, max Volume is 1000
    Dim Volume As Integer = (SFXVolume * 100)
    mciSendString("setaudio myWAV volume to " & Volume, Nothing, 0, 0)
```

Now this code I have tested and is working perfectly when filename1 = "C://Correct.wav"

However when I use

filename1 = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Correct.wav"

I get no sound play whatsoever.

Could anyone please help me correct my code so that this works.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value of mciSendString().  Bad idea, that's how it tells you that the function failed.  So you don't know why it doesn't work because you don't check for failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DirectoryPath` has spaces then `mciSendString` won't be able to recognize the command accurately, you need to surround the path with quotes:

```
mciSendString(
    String.Format("open ""{0}"" type mpegvideo alias myWAV", fileName1), Nothing, 0, 0)
```

Be sure to check returned status as well, as Hans suggests.

Also, since you don't know whether `DirectoryPath` has a trailing backslash or not, the accurate way to produce full path from directory and name is:

```
fileName1 = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Correct.wav")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use   `Private Declare Function SetCurrentDirectory Lib "kernel32" Alias "SetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long` then `SetCurrentDirectory filepath` before opening file for play. That is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DLL Call GetShortPathName in order to pass file paths to WINMM.DLL.
lpszLongPath is your full path string, and the short pathname will be passed to lpszShortPath.
cchbuffer should really be set to 200 or so, though in most cases, the returned string will be much shorter. You should use a VB padded string.

Private Declare Function GetShortPathName Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetShortPathNameA" (ByVal lpszLongPath As String, ByVal lpszShortPath As String, ByVal cchBuffer As Long) As Long

I have just used the mciSendString calls in a batch midi-file reading programme, opening 3642 midi files and returning copyright, title and play duration strings actually quite quickly!

Best Regards
David R Leach